# Cheating policy-Can you tell who has accessed an excel or access file?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

There is a final project due for my computer science class that utilizes excel and access.

The class has a strict file sharing policy that prohibits students from emailing these created documents. My question is whether and how assessors can tell if
A) a student has emailed these files and
B) can they tell if they have been accessed by the other student it was emailed to?
(Files are uploaded to blackboard for submission-not sure if this is relevant info)

Running into some grey areas and don't want to violate any policies.

Comment: You'd probably be best to ask the assessors or your professor for guidance, we can only speculate on how they implement their anti-plagiarism techniques. If you feel you can't ask them because whatever "grey area" activity you are participating in is likely to be looked upon in a bad light, you probably shouldn't be doing it. Also, why the `sql-server` tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about SQL Server and looks like it is trying to circumvent college anti-plagiarism policies

Answer (score 0):

a) Probably not if the name was changed so that it doesn't appear on the server logs
b) possibly if they have a hidden macro that logs file openings to a hidden worksheet.

Though if you think it feels bad enough to ask here, then it probably is not a good idea to do whatever you're thinking of doing...